# Перебор списка с добавлением в новый список

Tags: python, список, фильтрация

Перебор списка и добавление всех элементов в новый список, кроме варианта "подводной лодки".
Пробовал через not но не могу допереть, как лучше сделать.

```py
storage = ['коробка печенья', 'подводная лодка', 'краски', 'горшок для цветка', 'отвёртка', 'музыкальная пластинка', 'блокнот']

order = []

for rob in storage:
    if 'подводная лодка' != storage:
        order.append(rob)

print(order)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Готовая программа:

```
storage = ['коробка печенья', 'подводная лодка', 'краски', 'горшок для цветка', 'отвёртка', 'музыкальная пластинка', 'блокнот']
order = []
 
for rob in storage:
    if 'подводная лодка' != rob:
        order.append(rob)
 
print(order)
```

Comment: ну так исправьте на "правильно"

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Сравнивать, естественно, нужно не со всем списком `storage`, а с текущим элементом (переменной цикла):

```py
if 'подводная лодка' != rob:
                        ^^^
```

И на будущее - такое лучше делать через *списковое сокращение*, вместо четырёх строк получится одна:

```py
order = [rob for rob in storage if 'подводная лодка' != rob]
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!